Trouble setting up 2nd router as Access Point
I've spent a ton of hours trying to figure this out and the more I read the, the more I find that has different ways of doing it.
And I am losing my mind if it can actually be done
I have a Vodafone Ultra Hub as my main router.
And a TP-Link AC750 Archer C2 as my 2nd that I want to use as an access point for the extra Ethernet ports.
The trouble I'm having is when i get to the settings on the TP-Link settings.
I disable the DHCP and when i go to change the LAN IP it says that it cant be in the same subnet as the WAN IP.
I have a range set on the Ultra Hub and when I try to use those addresses nothing seems to work.
I've tried following the tutorial video on TP-Link's website and the only time I could set a LAN IP was after I deleted the WAN address and it was blank.
And does the Ethernet cable go into the WAN port as normal or into the LAN after everything has changed?
As far as I can tell on the settings, the TP-Link Archer C2 doesn't have a mode to change it into an access point.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Just disable the router part, and you're good to go. You can do this by simply not plugging in any cable in the WAN port, but only use the LAN ports. The wifi will still work. DHCP should indeed be disabled.

Thanks for the input.  All the help I've received has been of more use then the googling and multiple pages I had open for hours trying to get it to work


The cable connecting the Vodafone Ultra and the TP-Link AC750 should be plugged into a LAN port on both devices.
Nothing should be plugged into the WAN port on the TP-Link AC750
The Vodafone Ultra should be the only DHCP server on the local network.
The DHCP server on the TP-Link AC750 should be disabled.
To access the management interface on the TP-Link AC750, it should have its IP assigned using DHCP from the  Vodafone Ultra or you can set a static IP in the same subnet.
Clients that connect to the TP-Link AC750 will get their IP address assigned by the Vodafone Ultra and the TP-Link AC750 should act only as a wired switch and/or wireless access point.


TP-Link Archer C2 FAQs
How to configure the TP-Link wireless router as Access Point
What’s the difference between the Access Point Mode and Router Mode on the TP-Link wireless router?


Wow thank you very much, it only took 5 mins after reading your answer to get it working. I changed the DHCP on the AC750 before connecting it via Lan as I new I would get stuck sorting its IP. But its set and working great now.
